# Visual Studio 2017 profiler does not show function names

Tags: visual-studio-2017, profiler

I ran the Profiler (Alt+F2) in Visual Studio 2017 on several projects of mine, but they all show the same thing.

I get a table where under "Function Name" column, I only have the project exe name and PID number.

I am running in Release mode, x64, Local windows Debugger.

What could be the issue and how to fix it?

A simple example of a code I tested is:

```
#include <cstdio>

void func1()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}

void func2()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        func1();
    }
}

int main()
{
    func2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution, which was not written in all of the internet, and that is:

1. Reset VS settings by opening `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017` >
   run `devenv /ResetSettings`.
2. Check if there’s any setting/limitation
   for your machine, such as for CPU, for GPU, for Memory, by clicking the *settings icon* under the relevant tool under *Available Tools* in the *Performance Profiler* page.
3. Try to create a new solution and copy your sample code to this new solution then test again, this is useful for narrowing down this issue.